# Display Facebook Graph API likes count in my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, count, facebook-like

I'm using fields=fan_count in the Facebook Graph API to get the number of likes from my facebook page, but i don't know how to display the counter in my site.

That is the URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/gamersaction/?fields=fan_count&access_token=access_token

The URL is returning the number of likes and the id of my page:

[image]

I want to display only the fan_count field, how can i do it?

Comment: Go read up on the very basics of working with JSON/nested data structures in whatever programming language you are using.

Comment: This helped me find the simplest way to grab the like count for a project that I'm working on. It sounds like you'd be better off using a pre-made widget though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, id is the primary key.