# How to get the number of likes of a face book page through java?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

How to get the number of likes of a face book page through java? I want to get the count likes of a facebook page by providing the username. Can i get it without using access tokens?

Comment: Do you mean Java, or JavaScript (since you tagged this with `facebookfacebook-javascript-sdk`)? Are you aware that those are different things?

Comment: both are okay, java is preferable

Comment: You can not get it without an access token - but if the page is public and has no access restrictions of any kind applied, you can use your app access token. (Which means you must do it server-side, the app token should never be exposed in client-side code.)

Comment: okay thanq..i have created a app id and having access token for that app. Is it possible to access the count now? if so please provide me the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244827/display-facebook-graph-api-likes-count-in-my-site