# How to get number of likes only of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, facebook-likebox

I'm using this code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://web.facebook.com/mykliktransport/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

it is showing like this: [image]

but what is want is only the count to show it here : [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244827/display-facebook-graph-api-likes-count-in-my-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now... This may help
Get your token number from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

```
<?
 $fb_page = '1907481709532899'; 
 $access_token = 'Token Number';
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".$fb_page.'?access_token='.$access_token;
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $result = curl_exec($curl);  
 curl_close($curl);
 $details = json_decode($result,true);
 echo $details['likes'];
?>
```